# How to load firebase data before the component renders in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have the following files...

useAuthStatus.js

```
import {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const useAuthStatus = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true);
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted) {
      const auth = getAuth();

      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
          setLoggedIn(true);          
        }

        setCheckingStatus(false);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    }      
  }, [isMounted]);

  return {loggedIn, checkingStatus}
}

export default useAuthStatus
```

PrivateRoute.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuthStatus from '../hooks/useAuthStatus';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const {loggedIn, checkingStatus} = useAuthStatus();

  if (checkingStatus) {
      return <Spinner/>
  }

  return loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/sign-in' />
  
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Profile.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase.config';
import { getAuth, signOut, updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth';
import {doc, updateDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const Profile = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  const [changeDetails, setChangeDetails] = useState(false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: auth.currentUser.displayName,
    email: auth.currentUser.email
  });

  const {name, email} = formData;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onLogOut = async () => {
    await signOut(auth);

    navigate('/');
  }

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      if (auth.currentUser.displayName !== name) {
        //update display name in firebase auth
        await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: name
        });

        //update name in firestore
        const userRef = doc(db, 'users', auth.currentUser.uid);

        await updateDoc(userRef, {
          name: name
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Unable to change profile details');
    }
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => (
      {
        ...prevState,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
      }
    ))
  }


  return (
    <div className='profile'>
      <header className='profileHeader'>
        <p className='pageHeader'>My Profile</p>
        <button type='button' className='logOut' onClick={onLogOut}>Logout</button>
      </header>

      <main>
        <div className='profileDetailsHeader'>
          <p className='profileDetailsText'>Personal Details</p>
          <p className='changePersonalDetails' onClick={() => {
            changeDetails && onSubmit();
            setChangeDetails((prevState) => !prevState);
          }}>
            {changeDetails ? 'done' : 'change'}
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className='profileCard'>
          <form>
            <input type="text" id='name' className={!changeDetails ? 'profileName' : 'profileNameActive'} disabled={!changeDetails} value={name} onChange={onChange}/>

            <input type="text" id='email' className={!changeDetails ? 'profileEmail' : 'profileEmailActive'} disabled={!changeDetails} value={email} onChange={onChange}/>
          </form>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";

import Explore from './pages/Explore';
import ForgotPassword from './pages/ForgotPassword';
import Offers from './pages/Offers';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Explore />}/>
          <Route path="/offers" element={<Offers />}/>
          
          <Route path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />}/>
          <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />}/>
          <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />}/>
        </Routes>

        <Navbar />
      </BrowserRouter>

      <ToastContainer position="top-center" hideProgressBar={true} autoClose={3000} pauseOnHover={false}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the current working code...i'll briefly explain what's happening before proceeding to my question. When an unauthorized user visits "/profile" they get directed to PrivateRoute component. If the user is logged in then an `<Outlet/>` component from react router gets rendered and then the Profile component get rendered. However, If the user is not logged in then they are redirected to "/sign-in" by PrivateRoute. Please also note the nested routes in App.jsx.

If I remove the line `<Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />` in App.jsx from the nested route and make it a normal route then when the Profile component loads I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null". I believe I'm getting this error because the component is loading before `const auth = getAuth();` (in Profile.jsx) has finished fetching the data and populating name and email in useState().

Now my question is, in useAuthStatus.js I am using getAuth() to fetch data then AGAIN I'm using getAuth() to fetch data in Profile.jsx. So why does the nested routes(original) code work and not this altered version? If I need to use getAuth() again in Profile.jsx then how come the data loads BEFORE the component? In the nested routes if the outer "/profile" uses getAuth() then does that data get transfered to the nested route too somehow?

Comment: It's unclear what you are referring to *other than* that there is some issue with the `getAuth` that you haven't included in your [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what it's doing. Please edit your post to include all relevant code you are working with or asking about. Please also include the full error message so we can see what it's referring to. Can you also clarify more clearly what exactly you are asking for? It sounds like you are basically asking why not using `PrivateRoute` doesn't work.

Comment: @DrewReese I have included the complete code for the files. My question is quite simple.  I need to figure out why the current nested route in App.jsx works and simply `<Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />` doesn't on its own (not in a nested route)...i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')". As mentioned in the question, `getAuth()` is being called again in Profile.jsx to fetch data...why is this so if PrivateRoute has already checked for user login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've grokked what you are asking now.

> Now my question is, in useAuthStatus.js I am using `getAuth()` to
> fetch data then AGAIN I'm using `getAuth()` to fetch data in
> `Profile.jsx.` So why does the nested routes(original) code work and
> not this altered version?

It seems the original version of your code with the protected route component worked for a few reasons:

1. The `PrivateRoute` component isn't accessing the `Auth` object directly. It uses the `useAuthStatus` hook which itself also doesn't directly access the `Auth` object directly. The `useAuthStatus` hook uses the `onAuthStateChanged` function to "listen" for changes in the auth state.
2. The `checkingStatus` state prevents the `Profile` component from being rendered until the auth status changes, either a user has logged in, or logged out. *There's actually bug in your code that doesn't update the `loggedIn` state when a user logs out.*
3. By the time a user has accessed the `"/profile"` route and logged in, the Firebase `Auth` object has cached the user.

The altered version that directly accesses and renders `Profile` seems to fail because there is no current user value on the `Auth` object as the error points out.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')
```

Profile

```
const Profile = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  const [changeDetails, setChangeDetails] = useState(false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: auth.currentUser.displayName, // auth.currentUser is null!
    email: auth.currentUser.email
  });

  ...
```

All the firebase code appears to be synchronous:

[getAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getauth)

> Returns the Auth instance associated with the provided FirebaseApp. If
> no instance exists, initializes an Auth instance with
> platform-specific default dependencies.
>
> ```
> export declare function getAuth(app?: FirebaseApp): Auth;
> ```

[Auth.currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authcurrentuser)

> The currently signed-in user (or null).
>
> ```
> readonly currentUser: User | null;
> ```

The `Auth.currentUser` object is either going to be an authenticated user object or null. The `Profile` component is attempting to access this `currentUser` property prior to the component mounting to set the initial state value for the initial render.

You *could* use a null-check/guard-clause or Optional Chaining Operator on the `Auth.currentUser` property combined with a Nullish Coalescing Operator to provide a fallback value:

```
const Profile = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  const [changeDetails, setChangeDetails] = useState(false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: auth.currentUser?.displayName ?? "", // displayName or ""
    email: auth.currentUser?.email ?? ""       // email or ""
  });

  ...
```

But this only sets the value when the component mounts and only if there was an authenticated user. It's best to stick to using the `onAuthStateChanged` method to handle the auth state.

Now about the `loggedIn` bug:

```
const useAuthStatus = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true; // <-- use local isMounted variable
    
    const auth = getAuth();

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (isMounted) { // <-- check if still mounted in callback
        setLoggedIn(!!user); // <-- coerce User | null to boolean
        setCheckingStatus(false);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    }      
  }, []);

  return { loggedIn, checkingStatus };
};
```

> If I need to use `getAuth()` again in `Profile.jsx` then how come the
> data loads BEFORE the component?

You need to use `getAuth` any time you need to access the `Auth` object.

> In the nested routes if the outer "/profile" uses `getAuth()` then
> does that data get transferred to the nested route too somehow?

Not really. It is rather that your app has a single Firebase instance, which has a single `Auth` object that is accessed. In this way it is more like a global context. Firebase does a fair amount of caching of data to handle intermittent offline capabilities.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explaination. Things are started to make sense now. Just one issue, in the last part you mentioned "your app has a single Firebase instance, which has a single Auth object that is accessed. In this way it is more like a global context. Firebase does a fair amount of caching of data"...Am I correct in assuming that because getAuth() was accessed in useAuthStatus.js hence a copy of it was cached in the application and when Profile.jsx AGAIN called getAuth() then that saved copy was used to retrieve the data and popluate the variables in useState()??

Comment: Also, regarding the loggedIn bug...can you please explain why you're choosing to use a local variable instead of useRef()? Will choosing one over the other in this case cause any issues?

Comment: @falahmahmood I linked the docs, `getAuth` "Returns the Auth instance associated with the provided FirebaseApp.", so once an Auth instance is created, it's always the same one.

Comment: @falahmahmood About using the local variable over the Ref. Chances are there's been a React warning regarding the `isMounted` ref stating something to the effect of "...possibly changing values before the `useEffect` hook cleanup function is run, save a copy first and reference that...". Using a local variable is more logical here since it's the only place it needs to be referenced. It's programming pattern of limiting the scope of variables only to what they need.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help. It's all clear now.